# I am trying to upload my data to php my admin using a modal but unable to do. I don`t know which error I am getting . Help me this

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to submit data but data is not updated in php my admin. Can anyone help e with this where I am getting Error.

I have tried many ways but unable to locate my error.

Below is my function I want to submit a form :

```
    function add_ip() {


if(isset($_POST['add_ip'])) {


$name           = escape_string($_POST['name']);
$gender         = escape_string($_POST['gender']);
$age            = escape_string($_POST['age']);
$diagnosis      = escape_string($_POST['diagnosis']);
$date           = escape_string($_POST['date']);
$room           = escape_string($_POST['room']);
$doctor         = escape_string($_POST['doctor']);
$nurse          = escape_string($_POST['nurse']);  

$query = query("INSERT INTO ipd(name,gender,age,diagnosis,date,room,doctor,nurse) VALUES('{$name}','{$gender}','{$age}'),'{$diagnosis}','{$date}','{$room}','{$doctor}','{$nurse}'");
confirm($query);

set_message("Patient Added");

redirect("ipd.php");



}



}
```

FORM:

```
                        <?php add_ip(); ?>

                        <div class="form-group form-float">

                            <div class="form-line">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Patient Name" required autofocus>



                            </div>

                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="with-gap">

                            <label for="male">Male</label>



                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="with-gap">

                            <label for="female" class="m-l-20">Female</label>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-float">

                            <div class="form-line">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" required>

                                <label class="form-label">Age</label>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-float">

                            <div class="form-line">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosis" required>

                                <label class="form-label">Probable Diagnosis</label>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-float">

                            <div class="form-line">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" required>

                                <label class="form-label">Date of Admission</label>

                            </div>

                            <div class="help-info">YYYY-MM-DD format</div>

                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group form-float">

                            <div class="form-line">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="room" required>

                                <label class="form-label">Room Number</label>

                            </div>

                        </div>





                        <div class="form-group form-float">

                            <div class="form-line">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="doctor" required>

                                <label class="form-label">Reporting Doctor</label>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-float">

                            <div class="form-line">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nurse" required>

                                <label class="form-label">Assigned Nurses</label>

                            </div>

                        </div>



                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >

                    </form>
```

I am trying to submit data but data is not updated in php my admin. Can anyone help e with this where I am getting Error.

I have tried many ways but unable to locate my error.

Comment: you mean database not phpmyadmin

Comment: Turn on error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove paranthesis after `'{$age}'` and add it after the `'{$nurse}'`

```
VALUES('{$name}','{$gender}','{$age}','{$diagnosis}','{$date}','{$room}','{$doctor}','{$nurse}')
```

Answer (score 0):

First print the POST data , in your function so that you will get to know that whether you are getting data correctly or no,
once you get the data.
There is one error in your Sql query

```
  ,'{$age}'),'{$diagnosis}',
```

here you have added UN-necessary ")" please remove it, and check

Answer (score 0):

You recieve `$_POST('add_ip')` in function but you haven't send anything like **add_ip** in form

and try to print your sql query and check in mysql/phpmyadmin whether your **query works proper or not**.